# Hadoop to create an Index and Add() it to distributed SOLR... is this possible? Should I use Nutch? ..Cloudera?

Tags: solr, hadoop, nutch, solrnet, faceted-search

Can I use a MapReduce framework to create an index and somehow add it to a distributed Solr?

I have a burst of information (logfiles and documents) that will be transported over the internet and stored in my datacenter (or Amazon).  It needs to be parsed, indexed, and finally searchable by our replicated Solr installation.

Here is my proposed architecture:

- Use a MapReduce framework (Cloudera, Hadoop, Nutch, even [DryadLinq](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/dryadlinq/default.aspx)) to prepare those documents for indexing
- Index those documents into a Lucene.NET / Lucene (java) compatible file format
- Deploy that file to all my Solr instances
- Activate that replicated index

If that above is possible, I need to choose a MapReduce framework.  Since Cloudera is vendor supported and has a ton of patches not included in the Hadoop install, I think it may be worth looking at.

Once I choose the MatpReduce framework, I need to tokenize the documents (PDF, DOCx, DOC, OLE, etc...), index them, copy the index to my Solr instances, and somehow "activate" them so they are searchable in the running instance.  I believe this methodolgy is better that submitting documents via the REST interface to Solr.

The reason I bring .NET into the picture is because we are mostly a .NET shop.  The only Unix / Java we will have is Solr and have a front end that leverages the REST interface via Solrnet.

> Based on your experience, how does
>   this architecture look?  Do you see
>   any issues/problems?  What advice can
>   you give?

What should I *not* do to lose faceting search?  After reading the Nutch documentation, I believe it said that it does not do faceting, but I may not have enough background in this software to understand what it's saying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, you what you've described is almost exactly how Nutch works. Nutch is an crawling, indexing, index merging and query answering toolkit that's based on Hadoop core.

You shouldn't mix Cloudera, Hadoop, Nutch and Lucene. You'll most likely end up using all of them:

- **Nutch** is the name of indexing / answering (like Solr) machinery.
- Nutch itself runs using a **Hadoop** cluster (which heavily uses it's own distributed file system, HDFS)
- Nutch uses **Lucene** format of indexes
- Nutch includes a query answering frontend, which you can use, or you can attach a **Solr** frontend and use Lucene indexes from there.
- Finally, **Cloudera Hadoop Distribution** (or CDH) is just a Hadoop distribution with several dozens of patches applied to it, to make it more stable and backport some useful features from development branches. Yeah, you'd most likely want to use it, unless you have a reason not to (for example, if you want a bleeding edge Hadoop 0.22 trunk).

Generally, if you're just looking into a ready-made crawling / search engine solution, then Nutch is a way to go. Nutch already includes a lot of plugins to parse and index various crazy types of documents, include MS Word documents, PDFs, etc, etc.

I personally don't see much point in using .NET technologies here, but if you feel comfortable with it, you can do front-ends in .NET. However, working with Unix technologies might feel fairly awkward for Windows-centric team, so if I'd managed such a project, I'd considered alternatives, especially if your task of crawling & indexing is limited (i.e. you don't want to crawl the whole internet for some purpose).

Comment: +1, thanks! Is it possible for me to add metadata to each content that is to be index? I have to save the folder name and other metadata to each indexed document.

Comment: Also, do you know if Nutch will support faceted search?  Any links on querying using nutch would be appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, you're free to add any attributes to the document when you check it into the index. Basically, Nutch is a just a powerful parallelizer for Lucene indexing, while you still can do everything you can with Lucene. There's a good application that demonstrates its power: Luke - http://www.getopt.org/luke/ - you can both view your indexes document-by-document, edit it and make sophisticated queries with Luke.

Comment: So Nutch + Cloudera for input... and possibly SOLR for query and output if I like the REST-full query interface?  Not sure if Nutch  supports REST

Comment: Nutch on Hadoop on Cloudera Hadoop Distribution for crawling/indexing/index maintenance, possibly Solr if you need intricate queries. Nutch includes index querying (i.e. searching) capabilities mostly as demo, you can end up writing index querying yourself, so Solr might be a good choice. There's a a good presentation available at http://www.slideshare.net/gsingers/trihug-lucene-solr-hadoop on organizing your own search engine using Hadoop/Lucene-centric technologies.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Lucandra https://github.com/tjake/Lucandra a Cassandra based back end for Lucense/Solr which you can use Hadoop to populate the Cassandra store with the index of your data.

Comment: Sounds like I have learning to do.  I don't know what Cassandra is, or where it fits in...